# How to open Google Drive links directly in Google Drive app

Tags: ios, google-apps

Is there a way to do this?
Currently, the GDrive links I click in my emails open in Safari.

Is this currently a limitation of the app (or iOS 7)? Is there a configuration I can change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the links in the Gmail app for iOS, and you have the necessary Google Drive app installed (Google Drive, Google Docs, Google Sheets, and/or Google Slides), Gmail will by default open the links in a Google Drive app. You can enable or disable that feature in Gmail through Menu > Settings > Google Apps.

Alternatively (though it's less direct), you can paste the link into Chrome for iOS, and there will be a bar at the top of the page to open the link in a GDrive app.

Comment: Yes, with iOS 8 this is now possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you can prepend the url with the respective Google app to which it belongs. So if it is a Google Sheet, prepend the url with `Googlesheets://`. If it is a doc, I'm guessing you would use `Googledocs://`

So if the url is `http://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/Google-document/`, amend it with the appropriate app prefix (in this case `Googlesheets://` like so: `Googlesheets://http://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/Google-document`.

PS: The issue is discussed at length [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/docs/oc_gLA1Q86c).

Comment: Looks like two google employees saw the pre-edited version, else why the downvotes?  ;)

Comment: To "append" means to put on the end. To "prepend" means to put at the beginning. You mean "prepend", not "append".

Comment: Updated original comment with corrections.